# If silent is an adjective, what are silence(n), silenced (verb), silently (adv) called? The cognate of silent?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

I'm trying to find the term to describe a group of words in different forms (noun, verb, adjective, adverb) that is derived from the same word.

I found that cognate refers to the derivation of a word but in another language. Here i'm taking about word in a same language that got their suffix and prefix changed to form a different word form.

It's not cognate, it's not conjugation, then what is it?

Comment: Need to ask, logo of a noose?

Comment: You have "derived" and "derivation" in your question but not "**derivative**".

Comment: One problem here is that "word1 and word2 are **cognate**" is agnostic as to which (if either) is the "**root**" word, so it doesn't matter which order you give them in. But to use **derivative** correctly you need to know which is the root - and there will be many situations where even competent native speakers might be unsure as to which of multiple possible candidates really ***is*** the root from which all the others are derived.